# Obtain two dimensional linear space on trapezoid shape inside image frame

Tags: coordinates, coordinate-transformation

[image]

In this image, the black frame is a frame of an image, and the trapezoid is a rectangular plane as seen by a camera.

I know the pixel coordinate of the 4 corners and can iterate through each pixel inside that trapezoid. Since I don't/cannot know the transformation/rotation vectors from camera to plane, I'd like to transform the pixels into [0,0] [1,1] coordinates according to the position inside that trapezoid, so that I choose a point inside the trapezoid and obtain some coordinates in the [0, 0] [1, 1] range.

By linear space, I mean create a number of values that range from 0 to 1 linearly. So, a unidimensional linear space from 0 to 1 in 100 steps would look like [0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03 ... 1]. In this case, I'd like to do this but in two dimensions in the trapezoid. If this were a rectangle it would be trivial, I'm not sure there is a way to do this for a trapezoid.

For example, each point in the line of left side of the trapezoid would be always X=0, and y going from 0 to 1 linearly as you move "up" (though X coordinate actually changes in the image frame).

Comment: Have a look at [barycentric coordinates for convex quads](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3154041/3426025)

Comment: Or you may want to go through homogeneous coordinates like in the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10839998/3426025)

Comment: I think this is more like it.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13404/mapping-irregular-quadrilateral-to-a-rectangle

Answer (score 1):

I've made an example in Javascript [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/trapezoid-coordinates/5084709529387008). Below is an explanation of the mathematics behind it.

Name the points, clockwise, starting at `(0, 0)`, A, B, C, D. Then we can define a point along the left side, Q, as a linear combination of A and B:

```
Qx = Ax * (1 - v) + Bx * v
Qy = Ay * (1 - v) + By * v
```

Or

```
Qx = Ax + dx1 * v
Qy = Ay + dy1 * v
```

Where `dx1 = Bx - Ax` and `dy1 = By - Ay`

And a point along the right side, R, as a linear combination of D and C:

```
Rx = Dx + dx2 * v
Ry = Dy + dy2 * v
```

Where `dx2 = Cx - Dx` and `dy2 = Cy - Dy`

We can then draw a line from Q to R. With v = 0, we have the line AD, with v = 1, we have the line BC. As v goes from 0 to 1, we get lines that cover the whole of the trapezoid (assuming it is convex).

So any point P inside the trapezoid can be a linear combination of Q and R:

```
Px = Qx * (1 - u) + Rx * u
Py = Qy * (1 - u) + Ry * u
```

So a point `(Px, Py)` can be written:

```
Px = (Ax + dx1 * v) * (1 - u) + (Dx + dx2 * v) * u
Py = (Ay + dy1 * v) * (1 - u) + (Dy + dy2 * v) * u
```

Now we have two equations in two unknowns.

Expand and collect `v`s

```
v = (Px - Ax + u.Ax - u.Dx) / (dx1 - u.dx1 + u.dx2)
v = (Py - Ay + u.Ay - u.Dy) / (dy1 - u.dy1 + u.dy2)
```

Some more substitutions to simplify the calculations:

```
dx3 = Ax - Dx
dy3 = Ay - Dy
dx4 = dx2 - dx1
dy4 = dy2 - dy1
dx5 = Px - Ax
dy5 = Py - Ay
```

To get:

```
v = (dx5 + u.dx3) / (dx1 + u.dx4)
v = (dy5 + u.dy3) / (dy1 + u.dy4)
```

Set them equal

```
(dx5 + u.dx3) / (dx1 + u.dx4) = (dy5 + u.dy3) / (dy1 + u.dy4)
```

Cross multiply

```
(dx5 + u.dx3) * (dy1 + u.dy4) = (dy5 + u.dy3) * (dx1 + u.dx4)
```

Expand

```
dx5 * dy1 + dx5 * dy4 * u + dx3 * dy1 * u + dx3 * dy4 * u^2 = dy5 * da1 + dy5 * dx4 * u + dy3 * dx1 * u + dy3 * dx4 * u^2
```

Collect terms

```
(dx3 * dy4 - dy3 * dx4)u^2 + (dx5 * dy4 - dy5 * dx4 + dx3 * dy1 - dy3 * dx1)u + dx5 * dy1 - dy5 * dx1 = 0
```

This is a quadratic of the form `ax^2 + bx + c = 0`
Solve with quadratic formula

```
a = dx3 * dy4 - dy3 * dx4
b = dx5 * dy4 - dy5 * dx4 + dx3 * dy1 - dy3 * dx1
c = dx5 * dy1 - dy5 * dx1;
determinant = b * b - 4 * a * c
```

If determinant >= 0

```
u = (-B + sqrt(determinant)) / (2 * A)
```

Then plug `u` back into this equation to get `v`:

```
v = (dx5 + u.dx3) / (dx1 + u.dx4)
```